PromQL: Choose scalar conditionally
I have a Grafana graph where I'd like to show the results from a PromQL query with a conditional value being factored in.
The query is simple, similar to this: node_cpu_seconds_total / 4.
But: My dashboard contains a variable $subsystem that either is filled with K or L. If the var equals K the quotient is 4, else it is 20.
I tried something like this, but had no success: node_cpu_seconds_total / ((4 and ($subsystem == "K")) or 20).
I think this would work by using the bool operator, but for the heck of it cannot find any usable documentation how to use it properly and I just can't get it together intuitively. Another thing I read about was using the on() operation, but the examples did not help much in my case.
Is there a way to solve this within PromQL?

Afaik, you cannot compare strings directly in promql. But you can use some tricks with function absent. Maybe queries from this answer might inspire you.

Can you use key,value dashboard variable?
